# ASP.net debug https on localhost

Tags: asp.net, https

I have to test a method out on my asp.net application that should work on https. Is there a way where I can run the application on localhost on https so I can debug it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YOu could create a self signed SSL certificate and then create a web app with SSL and your self signed certificate on your local machine in IIS (use a URL like http://dummy.test and add that to the hosts file in the c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc folder, have it point to 127.0.0.1), then start VS, attach to the w3wp.exe process and you can debug.

[Create a self-signed SSL certificate with IIS 6.0 Resource Kit SelfSSL](http://www.somacon.com/p42.php)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, get yourself a self-signed cert and install it. Generally, though, I'd just disable the need for SSL in the local dev environment.